# Pass a variable to d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am going a bit mad here.

I am using d3.json to get some data within a loop but I need pass a variable into d3.json, which happens to be an index of a nodes.name item. I am trying to build up my nodes.links data.

How can I pass that variable in. The loop runs too quickly for a start.

Something like this.

```
for (i=0; i < length; i++;) {

var foo = nodes.name[i].index; // Imagine foo is updated every time the loop runs

d3.json(blah, function(error, data) {
  console.log(foo); //logs nodes.name[i].index value when passed; 
});
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can just reference `i` inside the callback.

Comment: The loop runs too quickly so whatever foo is has changed to the last item in the loop.

Comment: So if it was i and the length was 3 I would just 3 each time

Comment: Ah I see. You could wrap it in a function: `function bar(foo) { d3.json(blah, function(error,  data) { ... }); }`

Comment: Ah good idea. I will try that. Not sure why I didn't think of that.